# create c# method that will have parameter like the Dictionary<T,T1> object initializer

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that takes a dictionary as a parameter like this:

```
void Do(Dictionary<string,string> d)
```

I would like to create a method that I would be able to call just like the dictionary collection initializer, like this:

```
Do({"sadfs","sdfsa"}, {"sadda","sada"}, ...);
```

anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: I have seen this same question a few weeks ago. IMO, it's not possible. It's not even supported by the language syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't - you can use a collection initializer, but you *do* have to specify the type:

```
Do(new Dictionary<string, string> { {"x", "y"}, {"a", "b" } });
```

If the dictionary is going to be the same every time and you know that the method doesn't mutate it, I'd extract it to a static readonly variable, which has the benefit that you can give it a meaningful name.

Comment: it's going to be the same type every time <string, string> but it will be different keyvaluepairs (values, and count of them) all the time, the method won't change it, it will just read through it

Comment: You could simply use the `System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary` class instead no?

Comment: @SuperOli: Well maybe - but I'd suggest not doing so. Using a generic type allows all of the benefits of LINQ to Objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your method like this

```
public static void TheMethod(IDictionary<string, string> d)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(d.Count);
        // Other processing
    }
```

and call it like this

```
public static void MyMethod(string s)
    {
        TheMethod("name, value");
    }
```

If you want to pass more than one argument, then just change the definition to..

```
public static void TheMethod(ICollection<IDictionary<string, string>> d)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(d.Count);
        // Other processing
    }

public static void MyMethod(string s)
    {
        TheMethod("name, value", "otherName, otherValue");
    }
```